# The sidebar always shows the wrong page as "active"

Tags: dokuwiki

Whenever I create a new page in the sidebar, it always has the "active" state in the sidebar nav. When I go to other pages, the newly created page still has the active state.

I'm new to Dokuwiki, but any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable caching in the sidebar using the ~~NOCACHE~~ macro.